# OAUTH Login URI in Amazom SP-API Authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-selling-partner-api

I created a public App for Amazon SP-API.
While updating the App, there were 2 mandatory fields. **OAuth Login URI** and OAuth Redirect URI. My concern is about the OAuth Login URI. I am not able to save with updating just the OAuth Redirect URI.
I would want to implement the Amazon SP-API Oauth2 only after the user has logged into my website.
When I save the application after filling the two fields, this is what is happening.

1. User Logs into Amazon.
2. Authorized the App.
3. He is shown a list of items the App requests access to.
4. There is a button at the bottom **sign/up Login to App**
5. Once user clicks on the button, it goes to the **OAuth Login URI**
6. My application has to do the additional step of routing to amazon_callback_uri.
   While the below URL talks about the flow going to the OAuth Redirect URI.

https://developer-docs.amazon.com/amazon-business/docs/website-authorization-workflow

Can you please help me avoid this redirecting to the Login URI and rather redirect to OAuth Redirect URI?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon will redirect to the login URL if you are not using `state` in the authorization URL.

Here is an example authorization URL that you can use

```
https://sellercentral.amazon.in/apps/authorize/consent?application_id={application_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_urld}&state={state}
```

Once you have provided some value for `state`, on successful authorization amazon will directly redirect the user to the defined `redirect_uri` instead of redirecting to `login_uri`.